# Understanding Dini continuity for lifts of circle endomorhpisms

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

A function $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is said to be Dini continuous if its modulus of continuity $$\omega(t)=\sup_{|x-y|\leq t}|F(x)-F(y)|$$ satisfies $$\int_0^1\frac{\omega(t)}{t}dt<\infty.$$

I can clearly see that a Dini continuous function must be continuous, for otherwise $\omega(t)\nrightarrow0$ as $t\rightarrow0$ and the integral would be infinite. And in the case where the domain of $F$ is open, it is easy to come up with examples of functions which are continuous (and, in fact, differentiable) but not Dini continuous, e.g. $F(x)=x^2, e^x, \log(x)$, etc with domain $\mathbb{R^{+}}$.

However, I am currently reading a paper that uses the notion of Dini continuity for lifts $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ of circle endomorphisms $f:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ of degree $n$. That is, $\pi\circ F=f\circ\pi$, where $\pi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow S^1$ is the usual covering map $\pi(x)=e^{2\pi ix}$, and $F(x+1)=F(x)+n$. Assume from now on that $F$ is such a function.

This seems to place a tight restriction on the types of functions we are considering. I wonder if anyone could help my understanding by supplying any of the following examples.

(1) An $F$ that is continuous but not Dini continuous.

(2) An $F$ that is differentiable but not Dini Continuous.

(3) An $F$ that is differentiable but $\log F'(x)$ is not Dini continuous.

Thanks.